# Is the HTTP(s) version from a HTTPS response header also defined as HTTP/x.x? Or like HTTPS/x.x?

Tags: http, https

##### Is the HTTP(s) version from a HTTPS response header also defined as HTTP/x.x? Or like HTTPS/x.x?

I have searched on the internet and due to the absence of information I assume it is still `HTTP/x.x`, though I would like be to sure.

Comment: It's still just `HTTP/1.1`, on HTTP/2 it's a bit more complicated and it doesn't exactly exist in the same way.

Comment: @Evert - Allright thanks! How is HTTP/2 more complicated? Could you explain or perhaps a link to where I can learn it myself. I was unable to find it at [rfc7540](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html).

Comment: @Evert Or does it still show the HTTP/1.1 version while sending the response in frames?